# PSYoungGen has wrong space

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I test some jvm arguments to show GC logs,and find some details not as I wish, Maybe I was wrong?

```
public class EdenDemo {

private static final int _1MB = 1024 * 1024;

/**
 * vm arguments：-verbose:gc -Xms20M -Xmx20M -Xmn10M -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:SurvivorRatio=8
 */

public static void testAllocation(){
    byte[] allocation1, allocation2, allocation3, allocation4;
    allocation1 = new byte[2 * _1MB];
    allocation2 = new byte[2 * _1MB];
    allocation3 = new byte[2 * _1MB];
    allocation4 = new byte[4 * _1MB];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    testAllocation();
}

}
```

the jvm arguments

> -verbose:gc -Xms20M -Xmx20M -Xmn10M -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:SurvivorRatio=8

the gc logs

> [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 6794K->990K(9216K)]
>   6794K->5094K(19456K), 0.0041458 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00,
>   real=0.00 secs]  Heap  PSYoungGen      total 9216K, used 7372K
>   [0x00000000ff600000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)   eden
>   space 8192K, 77% used
>   [0x00000000ff600000,0x00000000ffc3b718,0x00000000ffe00000)   from
>   space 1024K, 96% used
>   [0x00000000ffe00000,0x00000000ffef7910,0x00000000fff00000)   to
>   space 1024K, 0% used
>   [0x00000000fff00000,0x00000000fff00000,0x0000000100000000)  ParOldGen 
>   total 10240K, used 4104K [0x00000000fec00000, 0x00000000ff600000,
>   0x00000000ff600000)   object space 10240K, 40% used
>   [0x00000000fec00000,0x00000000ff002020,0x00000000ff600000)  Metaspace 
>   used 3244K, capacity 4496K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K   class
>   space    used 350K, capacity 388K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K

why the PSYoungGen space size is 9216k(9M) not 10M?
 I already set "-Xmn 10M"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting your logs

```
... eden space 8192K, 77% used ...
... from space 1024K, 96% used ...
... to space 1024K, 0% used ...
```

Young space `-Xmn` is a sum of eden, S0, S1 (`from` and `to` are same as S0, S1, though S0 have `from` role for half of collections and `to` role for others, same for S1).

`eden` + `from` + `to` = 10MiB as expected.

Though, due to [logic of young collection](https://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html), `to` space should have zero utilization at all times, so effective capacity of young space is `eden` + `from` thus 9 MiB.

In general, though, some GC variant can dynamically adjust young space size (only reduce it compared to `-Xmn`) so effective young space at runtime could be smaller than configured.